# Error when creating a new profile in SQL*PLUS

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I want to create a new profile in SQL plus.

I started off by creating a user, this worked:

```
create user myuser
identified by password;
```

Then I tried to create a profile, this didn't work:

```
create profile myuserprofile limit
sessions_per_user 2
connect_time 120
idle_time 30
failed_login_attempts 3
password_life_time 365;
```

This is the errors i received:

```
ORA-65048: error encountered when processing the current DDL statement in pluggable database XEPDB1
ORA-01435: user does not exist
```

I tried it on my laptop, the same result.

the next step would be to alter the user to have the profile.

Edit:

I connected as the system and was able to get rid of both the errors:

```
ORA-65048: error encountered when processing the current DDL statement in pluggable database XEPDB1
ORA-01435: user does not exist
```

However, the error still arises when I try and create the profile on my user

Edit2:

FIXED

I realised i did not have DBA privileges on my user.

```
GRANT DBA TO XYZ;
```

Thanks

Comment: this is not MySql.

Comment: Works fine for me in a pluggable database. What does `SELECT * FROM session_roles` say for you?

Comment: Hi, it comes up with this: http://prntscr.com/sdcnd3 . Do i need to install a pluggable SQL plus?